# Making Page read only based on Picklist value change after saving

Tags: workflow, page-layout, validation-rule, record-type

I have a field which is present in 4 Page Layouts . When Opportunity Stage is changed to 'Closed Won' , the field needs to be Read Only.

Solution : Created 4 additional Page Layouts where the field is marked as Read Only.

Question - Do I have to create 4 different Record Types , apart from the ones already present , and assign through 4 Workflows ? Or is there any alternative (apart from Validation Rule )

P.S - I have checked a few other similar questions in the forum. But those were for 1 Page layout while my question is whether I need to do the same if a field is present in 'n' number of page layouts?

Comment: yes that is the one option if you want to go for standard solution otherwise create a vf page and render field as per stage status.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu- So I need to create 'n' number of Page Layouts/Record Types/Workflow Field update- Right?

Comment: yes you need to.